# curiousity question on Lyapunov function of a nonlinear system

Tags: nonlinear-system

I've just begun studying nonlinear systems in my spare time.  I'm using 'Nonlinear System Theory' by Rugh. My question is if there is a universal way to find the Lyapunov function of an arbitrary system. It doesn't have to be the easiest way, just a universal method that always works.

This is merely a question of curiosity.

Also, if anyone has any suggestion for good self-study books for nonlinear systems, feel free to mention them.

Perhaps I should rephrase: if a Lyapunov function exists, is there a universal way to find it that usually works.  Existence is important.

Comment: "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" by Strogatz is a very classic book. It has very intuitive explanations and easy to read. http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Dynamics-And-Chaos-Applications/dp/0738204536

Comment: "My question is if there is a universal way to find the Lyapunov function of an arbitrary system." Unfortunately, no. Plenty of examples on math.se, say [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/187900).

Answer (score 0):

If you could always find a Lyapunov function you could always decide questions of stability.  That's too much to hope for: there are some problems for which stability is very hard to decide.

Comment: What if the system is known to be stable, or certain regions are known to be stable, etc.?  What about then?

Comment: In principle I think (under appropriate assumptions) the existence of a Lyapunov function was proved by J.L. Massera.  I don't know whether this produces a very explicit Lyapunov function.